# MySQL Error Code: 1264 Out of range value for column 'count' at row 1

Tags: mysql, underflow

I have some MySQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (  
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    count int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,  
    PRIMARY KEY (id)  
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert into test_table (count) values (1);
update test_table set count = IF( count -1 < 0, 0 , count -1 );
update test_table set count = IF( count -1 < 0, 0 , count -1 );
```

This should set count to zero if `(count -1) < 0`.

I get an error:

```
Error Code: 1264 Out of range value for column 'count' at row 1` instead.
```

This is due to count being an unsigned int.  If I use a signed int it works.

Is this a bug in MySQL?  I'm using:  `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.46sp1, for Win32 (ia32)`

Comment: this is not a bug
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=2454

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should be doing this:

```
UPDATE test_table
SET count = IF( count < 1, 0 , count -1 )
```

The value of `count - 1` underflows when `count` is zero.

```
SELECT count, count - 1 FROM test_table;
+-------+----------------------+
| count | count - 1            |
+-------+----------------------+
| 0     | 18446744073709551615 |
| 1     |                    0 |
| 2     |                    1 |
+-------+----------------------+
```

When I try your query, it doesn't work... but it doesn't fail in the same way as you see.

Comment: I still don't see any reason why it should fail. If (count -1) is signed and greater than zero, then it must be converted to an unsigned int before assigned to count. And as I'm never assigning anything less than zero to count, just zero if the test fails, this should be the same. Over to the solution. My problem here is that the -1 was just an example and can actually be any integer X. I could do IF( count < ABS(X), 0, count + X), though. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: EDIT: need to consider sign too: IF( count < ABS(X) AND SIGN(X) < 0, 0, count + X)

Comment: Thanks! So it's doing arithmetic with unsigned ints apparently. Makes sense, I guess. Just too used to programming where automatic type conversion is done for you on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

If count is unsigned, and its value is zero, then subtracting 1 from it gives a value out of range of an unsigned int. So correct error message and no bug, I think

Comment: But I'm not assigning the value to the field. Just using it as part of a test.

Comment: In the test, you're trying to calculate count -1 when count is zero.  That is an invalid calculation, since an unsigned value cannot represent count - 1. Mark Byers has the right idea - try not to use a value that is negative.